# Linux (command) | rename | trim leading chracters after x vs. keep only numbers

Tags: linux, command, rename

I want to delete some parts from file names such that

```
101 - title [1994].mp4
102 - title [1994].mp4
103 - title [1994].mp4
104 - title [1994].mp4
105 - title [1994].mp4
```

becomes

```
101.mp4
102.mp4
103.mp4
104.mp4
```

There are two or more ways to handle this, either by:

- keeping numbers and remove non-numbered characters
- trim leading characters after (3)-characters

How would I use the linux command `rename` to only keep the first (3) characters and trim the rest, while keeping the extension ofcourse.

I would like to avoid the `mv` command, what are the ways to do this with rename?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expression you want `s/(\d{3}).*$/$1.mp4/`. Take a look at the output:

```
rename -n 's/(\d{3}).*$/$1.mp4/' *mp4
101 - title [1994].mp4 renamed as 101.mp4
102 - title [1994].mp4 renamed as 102.mp4
103 - title [1994].mp4 renamed as 103.mp4
104 - title [1994].mp4 renamed as 104.mp4
105 - title [1994].mp4 renamed as 105.mp4
```